# MAGMA: function "magma_dgels_gpu" --> error "magma_trans_t"

Tags: cuda, nvcc, magma

I am trying to solve a least squares problem via "magma_dgels_gpu()" function of MAGMA Library. My GPU is "Tesla C2050 / C2075" and i have installed MAGMA.

I am trying to compile the below code "testMagmaDGELS.cu", but i get error:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cublas.h>

#include "magma.h"

#define UTILS_MALLOC(__ptr, __type, __size)                           \
  __ptr = (__type*)malloc((__size) * sizeof(__type));                 \
  if (__ptr == 0) {                                                   \
    fprintf (stderr, "!!!! Malloc failed for: %s\n", #__ptr );        \
    exit(-1);                                                         \
  }

#define UTILS_DEVALLOC(__ptr, __type, __size)                                 \
  if( cudaSuccess != cudaMalloc( (void**)&__ptr, (__size)*sizeof(__type) ) ){ \
    fprintf (stderr, "!!!! cudaMalloc failed for: %s\n", #__ptr );            \
    exit(-1);                                                                 \
  }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if( CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS != cublasInit( ) ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CUBLAS: Not initialized\n"); exit(-1);
    }

    double *devA, *devB, *pWork, lWorkQuery[1];
    const int M = 5, N = 3;

    int ret, info;

    /* Allocate device memory for the matrix (column-major) */
    int lda  = M;
    int ldda = ((M + 31) / 32) * 32;
    UTILS_DEVALLOC(devA, double, ldda * N);
    UTILS_DEVALLOC(devB, double, M);

    /* Initialize the matrix */
    double A[N][M] = {{ 0.6,  5.0,  1.0, -1.0, -4.2 },
                      { 1.2,  4.0, -4.0, -2.0, -8.4 },
                      { 3.9,  2.5, -5.5, -6.5, -4.8 }};
    cublasSetMatrix(M, N, sizeof(double), A, lda, devA, ldda);

    double B[M] = {3.0, 4.0, -1.0, -5.0, -1.0};
    cublasSetMatrix(M, 1, sizeof(double), B, M, devB, M);

    /* Resolve the LLSP using MAGMA */
    ret = magma_dgels_gpu('N', M, N, 1 /* nb of colums in the matrix B */,
                           devA, ldda, devB, M,
                           lWorkQuery, -1, // query the optimal work space
                           &info);
    if (info < 0) {
        printf("Argument %d of magma_dgels_gpu had an illegal value.\n", -info);
        exit(1);
    } else if (ret != MAGMA_SUCCESS) {
        printf("magma_dgels_gpu failed (code %d).\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }

    int lwork = (int)lWorkQuery[0];
    printf("Optimal work space %d\n", lwork);
    UTILS_MALLOC(pWork, double, lwork);

    ret = magma_dgels_gpu('N', M, N, 1 /* nb of colums in the matrix B */,
                           devA, ldda, devB, M,
                           pWork, lwork,
                           &info);
    if (info < 0) {
        printf("Argument %d of magma_dgels_gpu had an illegal value.\n", -info);
        exit(1);
    } else if (ret != MAGMA_SUCCESS) {
        printf("magma_dgels_gpu failed (code %d).\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("LLSP solved successfully\n");
    }

    cublasGetMatrix(M, 1, sizeof(double), devB, M, B, M);

    /* Expected solution vector: 0.953333 -0.843333 0.906667 */
    printf("Solution vector:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("\t%lf\n", B[i]);
    }

    /* Memory clean up */
    free( pWork );
    cudaFree( devA );
    cudaFree( devB );

    /* Shutdown */
    cublasShutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

I make compile as follows:

nvcc -arch=sm_20 testMagmaDGELS.cu -o testMagmaDGELS -lcublas -I/opt/magma/1.7.0/openblas/gcc/include

And I get these errors:

```
team24@tesla:~$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 testMagmaDGELS.cu -o testMagmaDGELS -lcublas -I/opt/magma/1.7.0/openblas/gcc/include
testMagmaDGELS.cu(54): error: argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "magma_trans_t"

testMagmaDGELS.cu(70): error: argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "magma_trans_t"

2 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00002d95_00000000-8_testMagmaDGELS.cpp1.ii".
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the magma type for indication of transpose/no transpose, instead of using a `char` type.

so instead of this:

```
ret = magma_dgels_gpu('N', ...
```

do this:

```
magma_trans_t my_trans = MagmaNoTrans;

ret = magma_dgels_gpu(my_trans, ...
```

See the documentation [here](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projectsfiles/magma/doxygen/constants.html).

> magma_trans_t  magma_trans_const   ( character )   Map 'N', 'T', 'C' 
>   to MagmaNoTrans, MagmaTrans, MagmaConjTrans

Comment: i get new error:  tmpxft_00003662_00000000-3_testMagmaDGELS.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x45e): undefined reference to `magma_dgels_gpu'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: That's a different issue.  It means you're not linking against the necessary magma library. Try adding `-L/opt/magma/1.7.0/lib -lmagma` to your compile command line.

Comment: Now i get:   /usr/bin/ld: warning: libopenblas.so.0, needed by /opt/magma/1.7.0/openblas/gcc/lib/libmagma.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
and next a lot of references like this one: "/opt/magma/1.7.0/openblas/gcc/lib/libmagma.so: undefined reference to `dorgql_'"

Comment: I am newbie to this...I make compile like this:      nvcc -arch=sm_20 testMagmaDGELS.cpp -o testMagmaDGELS -lcublas -I/opt/magma/1.7.0/openblas/gcc/include -L/opt/magma/1.7.0/openblas/gcc/lib -lmagma

Comment: That's another library you need to link in:`libopenblas.so`   Find out where it is on your system, then add the `-L` switch with the path to it, along with the `-lopenblas` switch to include the library.  You may want to learn about general linux build procedures and how to link in libraries.  Also figure out how to build a sample magma program before working on your own.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your answers! I will try to link the right libraries. ;)